Buildozer thinks can not find a file even though there is one
I'm currently making an apk from my kivy file using buildozer on a wsl and one of the requirements is kivymd version 2.0.1.dev0. I couldn't download it from github, so I got a .zip file. I compiled the app once. It did not run, but it was on my phone. I tweaked some things and now I run into this error message:
    Using pip 24.3.1 from /root/Yoga-Project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
WARNING: Requirement 'c:\\users\\pc\\downloads\\kivymd-master.zip' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing ./c:\users\pc\downloads\kivymd-master.zip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError.

I have checked the file. It is there. I looked inside the zip file. I copied the path. I pasted the path to the same place. Nothing. Maybe because my path has capital letters and this does not (but then again, how did it compile the first time?). I have no idea how to solve this

I have fixed the error. I just used the github link. Here are my requirements from buildozer.spec:
requirements=python3,kivy==2.3.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

It also turns out that buildozer decided to only use kivymd version 1.3.0 even though I deleted it once. Had to delete the .buildozer directory from my project directory. That caused problems down the line, so if anyone has the same issue, try to delete things properly. There should be a command in buildozer that cleans everything (although that will require another installation of all the components)
